# populate input fields from php / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I populate 50 html5 input fields from an external delimited "|" text file ("players.txt"):

```
Smith, Bob|Jones, James|Cavanaugh, Harvey|
```

I have input fields like so:

```
<input type="text" name = "N01" id = "I01">
<input type="text" name = "N02" id = "I02">

<script>
$jQuery.get('assets/players.txt', function(data) {
splitString = dataString.split("|");

$('#I01').val(splitString[0]);
$('#I02').val(splitString[1]);
$('#I03').val(splitString[2]);

});

</script>
```

Comment: change `function (data)` to `function(dataString)`

Comment: and please don't space `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let dataString = "Smith, Bob|Jones, James|Cavanaugh, Harvey|";
let splitString = dataString.split("|");

for (let i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
  $("#I0" + i).val(splitString[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="N01" id="I01">
<input type="text" name="N02" id="I02">
```

Comment: You should factor in what others have suggested, this example only works with the small amount of data provided. Since it hard codes the leading 0. For values >10 look at what CertainPerformance suggested with `padStart(2, '0')`

Comment: Yes, but the smart money is on removing the leading zeros, which I will always do henceforth. Thank for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting html elements using jquery `$` sign such as

```
$('#I01').val(splitString[0]);
$('#I02').val(splitString[1]);
$('#I03').val(splitString[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently referencing the wrong data variable `dataString`, instead reference `data`.  Also, if you know your IDs are sequential, you can avoid writing 50 different lines of JS and run a for loop, for instance:

```
for(i=0; i<splitString.length; i++){
  id = "#I0"+(i+1);
  $(id).val(splitString[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the value of each element individually, use a `forEach` loop.

Make sure to take into account string padding.

```
splitString.forEach((str, i) => {
  document.querySelector('#I' + String(i).padStart(2, '0'))
    .value = str;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example without ajax:**

```js
$(function(){
  var splitString = 'Smith, Bob|Jones, James|Cavanaugh, Harvey';
  splitString = splitString.split("|");
  $('#playersInputs').empty();
  $.each(splitString, function(i,v){
    $('<input type="text" />')
        .attr('name', 'N'+("0"+(i+1)).slice(-2))
        .attr('id', 'I'+("0"+(i+1)).slice(-2))
        .val(v)
        .appendTo('#playersInputs');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='playersInputs'>
</div>
```

**Example With ajax:**

you must replace `/path/to/your/text-file` with the `actual url`

```js
$(function(){
  $.get('/path/to/your/text-file', function(data) {
    var splitString = data.split("|");
    $('#playersInputs').empty();
    $.each(splitString, function(i,v){
      $('<input type="text" />')
          .attr('name', 'N'+("0"+(i+1)).slice(-2))
          .attr('id', 'I'+("0"+(i+1)).slice(-2))
          .val(v)
          .appendTo('#playersInputs');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='playersInputs'>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work with Run code snippet. But I do need an ajax version because the assets/players.txt is generated automatically

Comment: @verlager please give me the full url of your text file

Comment: Thanks but I fixed it with some php.

Comment: @verlager No problem :)